# Subset data.frame in R and calculate summary statistics, recombine with zero row subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to manipulate a very large data.frame with 40 variables and several hundred thousand observations.  I want to `subset` the data frame based on a column value, and add new column variables that are specific to the `subset`.  I am trying to subdivide based on the `age` in this case, calculate some basic stats on this `subset` and then build out three new columns across the whole dataset.

Here is an example:

```
  data.test <- data.frame( age = c( 1, 1.4, 1, 1.3, 4, 3.2, 3.3, 3.5, 4.3, 3.4, 4.6, 4.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3 ), 
                     class.type = c( "A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B","B","A","B","B","B","B","A" ))
```

I now want to add the following columns to the data.frame: `data.test$age.group` = the age category in integers `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, `data.test$count` = the number of observations in each age group, and `data.test$a.ratio` = that calculates the ratio of As to Bs.

I've tried the following:

```
 data_0 <- subset( data.test, age > 0 & age <= 1 )
 data_1 <- subset( data.test, age > 1 & age <= 2 )
 data_2 <- subset( data.test, age > 2 & age <= 3 )
 data_3 <- subset( data.test, age > 3 & age <= 4 )
 data_4 <- subset( data.test, age > 4 & age <= 5 )
```

then adding columns to each new `data.frame`

```
 data_0  <- data.frame( data_0, age.group = "0", count.row = nrow( data_0 ),
                        a.ratio = nrow(subset(data_0, class.type == "A"))/nrow( data_0))
 data_1  <- data.frame( data_1, age.group = "1", count.row = nrow( data_1 ),
                        a.ratio = nrow(subset(data_1, class.type == "A"))/nrow( data_1))
 data_2  <- data.frame( data_2, age.group = "2", count.row = nrow( data_2 ),
                        a.ratio = nrow(subset(data_2, class.type == "A"))/nrow( data_2))
 data_3  <- data.frame( data_3, age.group = "3", count.row = nrow( data_3 ),
                        a.ratio = nrow(subset(data_3, class.type == "A"))/nrow( data_3))
 data_4  <- data.frame( data_4, age.group = "4", count.row = nrow( data_4 ),
                        a.ratio = nrow(subset(data_4, class.type == "A"))/nrow( data_4))
```

Although not particularly nice code, this does work apart from the fact that the subset with ages between 2-3 has no data in it, so the following error is thrown `Error in data.frame(data_2, age.group = "2", count.row = nrow(data_2),  :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`.

If this error didn't get in the way I could just `rbind` all the `data_X` data.frames back together and be done.  However, I can't work around this zero row error and there surely must be a better way to do what I want to do, I'm just too inexperienced to figure it out.

Thanks for any help as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here is a tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)

data.test <-
  data.frame(
    age = c( 1, 1.4, 1, 1.3, 4, 3.2, 3.3, 3.5, 4.3, 3.4, 4.6, 4.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3 ), 
    class.type = c( "A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B","B","A","B","B","B","B","A" ))

data.test %>% 
  #age.group  = age as integer
  mutate(age.group = as.integer(age)) %>% 
  #count = the number of observations in each age.group
  add_count(age.group,name = "count") %>% 
  #Grouping by age.group
  group_by(age.group) %>% 
  mutate(
    #a.count = the number of observations with type A in each age.group
    a.count = sum(class.type == "A"),
    #b.count = the number of observations with type B in each age.group
    b.count = sum(class.type == "B"),
    #a.ratio = a.count/count
    a.ratio = a.count/count
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Vinicius, this looks neat and clean!  However, in my true dataset I have whole numbers between 0-4500 and I want to divide them into bins every 100 (0-100, 100-200, 200-300, etc).  I can't think of a clever way to do that with your mutate approach.  Can you?

Comment: You can use the function `cut()` @Jesse

Comment: Ahh okay.  One last thing, I think I wasn't clear what I was after with the `a.ratio`, but I wanted the proportion of values with `A`.  So, how would I get the total number of observations; something like `nrow(classt.type)`?

Comment: @Jesse I added the code in my answer, see if it works!

Comment: Okay, I'm actually looking for the proportion of `A` values to the total number of values that have either A or B.  So I think it should be `ab.ratio = a.count/(a.count+b.count)`

Comment: Ok, I you can use the `count` variable tha was calculated before. I updated the code

Answer (score 3):

It may be better to create a `list` object instead of multiple objects in the global env

```
lst1 <- lapply(1:5, function(i) subset(data.test, age > (i-1) & age <= i))
```

Then, we can create a check on the `list` elements whethe the number of rows are greater than 0, and then only we add the columns

```
i1 <- sapply(lst1, NROW) > 0
lst1[i1] <- Map(function(x, y) data.frame(x, age.group = y, 
         count.row = nrow(x), a.ratio = mean(x$class.type == 'A')), 
      lst1[i1], (0:4)[i1])
```

-output

```
> lst1
[[1]]
   age class.type age.group count.row a.ratio
1  1.0          A         0         5     0.4
3  1.0          B         0         5     0.4
13 0.4          B         0         5     0.4
14 0.1          B         0         5     0.4
15 0.3          A         0         5     0.4

[[2]]
  age class.type age.group count.row a.ratio
2 1.4          B         1         2     0.5
4 1.3          A         1         2     0.5

[[3]]
[1] age        class.type
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[4]]
   age class.type age.group count.row a.ratio
5  4.0          B         3         5     0.4
6  3.2          A         3         5     0.4
7  3.3          B         3         5     0.4
8  3.5          B         3         5     0.4
10 3.4          A         3         5     0.4

[[5]]
   age class.type age.group count.row a.ratio
9  4.3          B         4         3       0
11 4.6          B         4         3       0
12 4.7          B         4         3       0
```

---

Or we may use `cut` to create groups in a group by operation

```
library(dplyr)
data.test %>% 
   group_by(age.group = cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf, 0:5, Inf))) %>% 
   summarise(class.type = class.type, count.row = n(), 
       a.ratio = mean(class.type == 'A'), age, .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: These both look great, but before I mark them as answers, I want to make sure I understand.  How does the `mean(class.type == 'A')` work?  I don't understand what that is actually doing.  Now that I look at it, I don't quite understand the whole summarize function.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jesse It is based on the logical mean i.e. `v1 <- c(1, 1, 3, 5, 4)` Now, we convert to logical `v1 == 1`, where there are 2 TRUE values and mean of that will be `mean(v1 == 1)`
[1] 0.4# because TRUE/FALSE corresponds to 1/0 and that it is doing `sum(v1 == 1)/length(v1)`

Comment: @Jesse the second piece of code is related to doing a group operation instead of splitting of subsetting with `==`.  Once you have the grouping created, within `summarise`, there will be only a single row by group, but `dplyr::summarise` recently also allows  for multiple rows.  You get multiple rows only because the we are also returning the `class.type` column as it is